# ArgoCD ignoring undescribed fields

Tags: devops, argocd, gitops

ArgoCD ignore non described helm fields and think live manifest=desired manifest. Actually it's false.

If I omit some options of the helm template in my desired manifest and edit it in the k8s, then ArgoCD tell me all synced. But in real world there are some diffs.
What is the main reason? Is there some special flag to ignore it?

ArgoCD app settings:

```yaml
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: demo
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - ../values.yaml
    path: /application
    repoURL: git@myrepo.git
    targetRevision: main
  syncPolicy:
    retry:
      backoff:
        duration: 5s
        factor: 2
        maxDuration: 3m
      limit: 5
    syncOptions:
    - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true
    - Validate=false
    - CreateNamespace=true
    - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
    - PruneLast=true
```

Live helm app manifest:

```yaml
...
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                  - '-c'
                  - sleep 30
...
```

Desired helm app manifest:

```yaml
...
<NONE for this fields>
...
```

Diff is empty.

**P.S.**: I guess it's related to some kind of the "ignoreMissingValueFiles", but I don't have a setting like this in my config....

So, what is the option in the ArgoCD related to ignore non-described fields?